# Elasticsearch - Nest - specific search

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

In relation to the question:
[Elasticsearch/Nest - using MatchPhrase with OnFieldsWithBoost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169540/elasticsearch-nest-using-matchphrase-with-onfieldswithboost/28171329#28171329)

I have an index which looks something like this:

```
{
    "_index": "myIndex",
    "_type": "Page",
    "_id": "119",
    "_score": 0.104187615,
    "_source": {
        "dataBaseId": 119,
        "category": "InfoPage",
        "type": "Page",
        "metaTitle": "myMeta",
        "metaDescription": "Description",
        "rawText": "my search text"
    }
}
```

My code looks like this:

```
var result = ElasticClient.Search<SearchReportDocument>(s => s
            .Index("myIndex")
            .Type("Page")
            .Size(10)
            .Query(q =>
                q.MultiMatch(m => m.OnFieldsWithBoost(f => f.Add(b => b.MetaTitle, 5).Add(b => b.RawText, 1)).Type(TextQueryType.PhrasePrefix).Query(searchQuery))
                )
            );
```

I would like to extend it to only return results which has "category" equal to InfoPage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the structure of your index I assume that you have a `Page` class , so you can find the pages with that category as I show below:

```
 var result= client.Search<Page>(sd => sd.Index("myIndex")
                                  .From(0)
                                  .Size(10).Query(q =>
                                  q.MultiMatch( m =>
                                  m.OnFieldsWithBoost(f => f.Add(b => b.MetaTitle, 5).Add(b => b.RawText, 1))
                                  .Type(TextQueryType.PhrasePrefix)
                                  .Query(searchQuery))
                                  &&  q.Term("category", "infopage")));
```

Now, if you `SearchReportDocument`class has the same fields of `Page`, also you can find the pages this way:

```
  var result= client.Search<SearchReportDocument>(sd => sd.Index("myIndex").Type("Page")
                                  .From(0)
                                  .Size(10).Query(q =>
                                  q.MultiMatch( m =>
                                  m.OnFieldsWithBoost(f => f.Add(b => b.MetaTitle, 5).Add(b => b.RawText, 1))
                                  .Type(TextQueryType.PhrasePrefix)
                                  .Query(searchQuery))
                                  &&  q.Term("category", "infopage")));
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have a SearchReportDocument class, but my problem is I would like to still keep the rest of the search and extend it. So this part should still be a part of the search `q =>
                q.MultiMatch(m => m.OnFieldsWithBoost(f => f.Add(b => b.MetaTitle, 5).Add(b => b.RawText, 1)).Type(TextQueryType.PhrasePrefix).Query(searchQuery))`

Comment: I just tried searching with just `.Query(q => q.Term(p => p.Category, "InfoPage")));` and I get no results from the index.

Comment: I tried adding a filter. If I use Exists on the field category I get results. But if I add a Term to the filter like `Filter<SearchReportDocument>.Term("category", "InfoPage");` then the search finds no result.

Comment: Sorry, at first I didn't understand well what are you trying to do. I have updated my answer. Hope this help now

Comment: Thanks. One thing I found out, it is really important that the search criteria is lower case.

Answer (score 1):

Use [TermQuery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/term-query-usage.html)

Field:"category"

Value:"infopage"

---

example:

```
 List<QueryContainer> shoudQuery = new List<QueryContainer>();
List<QueryContainer> mustQuery = new List<QueryContainer>();


shoudQuery.Add(new MultiMatchQuery()
    {
        //your Query
    });
mustQuery.Add(new termQuery()
    {
       Field = "category",
       value= "infopage",    
    });


QueryContainer queryContainer = new BoolQuery
        {
             Should = shoudQuery.ToArray(),
             Must = mustQuery.ToArray(),
             MinimumShouldMatch = 1,

         };


var result = Client.Search(s => s.Size(resultSize).Query(q => queryContainer)
```